# Installing Using Terminal Brings Up Long List of Auto Removable 'Options'

Tags: apt, package-management

So I'm using the terminal to install a few programs, little minor things like visual boy advance and such. Every time I do, it makes a rather gigantic list of things that can be removed with autoremove and I have no idea if it's even safe to consider doing it or not. A lot of it sounds like very important things.

List as follows:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  alien app-install-data apt-xapian-index apturl-common at debugedit
  gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 guile-2.0-libs laptop-detect lib32z1 libc6-i386
  libcaca0:i386 libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcurl3:i386
  libdevmapper1.02.1:i386 libevent-2.0-5 libgail-common libgail18 libgc1c2
  libgsoap4 libidn11:i386 libjpeg62 libnatpmp1 libpod-plainer-perl
  libpython2.7:i386 libpython2.7-minimal:i386 libpython2.7-stdlib:i386
  libreadline6:i386 libreoffice-gtk librpmbuild3 librpmsign1 librtmp0:i386
  libsdl1.2debian:i386 libsigsegv2 libxmu6:i386 lsb-security m4 ncurses-term
  oneconf oneconf-common pax python-debtagshw python-lxml python-oneconf
  python-piston-mini-client python3-oneconf python3-piston-mini-client
  python3-xdg rpm software-center-aptdaemon-plugins transmission-common
  ubuntu-extras-keyring
```

Can someone tell me if this is normal and a viable thing to do, or if it's abnormal and to not use autoremove?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've never had any problems autoremoving, however, other users have reported the uninstallation of all kinds of stuff they didn't want to uninstall so there is the very real possibility of unforeseen consequences.

If you are the kind of person that would rather not have to fix things, you should probably leave it alone.